# Where are the save files for the Steam edition of Assassins Creed II located?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Where are the Assassins Creed II save files? I found a few locations in Google, but most of them do not exist on my system. I also found an article that Ubisoft patched AC2 to save locally. Are the save files for the Steam version located in the Steam cloud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the folder:

```
[User HOME Directory]/AppData/Local/Ubisoft Game Launcher/<RANDOM NAME>/4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the Assassin's Creed **3** save files:

In Windows 7 x64 I found the save games (not the config files) under this folder:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\savegames\{Unique Key}\54\
```

Where {Unique Key} is a personal ID for your UPlay account.

If you're on 32-bit Win 7 they're probably here:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\savegames\{Unique Key}\54\
```

I'm using the Steam version.  I would think that other versions would be the same but I can't be sure on that.

Other UPlay games are in similar locations, with a different number at the end.  For example, I *think* Far Cry 3 is under 46 and Assassin's Creed Revelations is under 40.

Generally, saves in these locations should be synced via UPlay but I've had problems with that working before so it's good to know where these are and have a backup.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the folder spoken of in the accepted answer, with the Steam version of Assassins Creed II. However, it appears that Uplay stores save game data in the cloud as I was able to start where I left off on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "Saved Games" folder on this path:

`%APPDATA%\Ubisoft\Assassin's Creed`

also written like:

`[DRIVE LETTER]:\Users\\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Ubisoft\Assassin's Creed.`

Replace `[DRIVE LETTER]` with the drive you are using and `[USERNAME]` with your username.

By the way, I am using a windows 7 computer.